# Qt remove Layout from other Layout

Tags: c++, qt, qlayout

[image: When I use delete layout_newInfo; layout_main->update() happends this.]How can I remove an layout_newInfo from layout_main in runtime (pressing button)?

[image: I need get this back after pressing button (next image)]

[image: Delete orange section (layout_newInfo) by pressing button Add Component]

code I tried:

```
    QLayout *layout = this->layout();

    QLayoutItem *item;
    while ((item = layout->takeAt(0)) != 0)
        layout->removeItem (item);
    delete layout_newInfo;
    layout_main->update();
```

Comment: Shows the code you've tried.

Comment: Added code to Qestien.

Comment: Note that the call `layout->removeItem (item);` in the `while` loop does nothing as the `item` passed has already been removed by the call to [`QLayout::takeAt`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#takeAt).

Answer (score 2):

What exactly do you want to achieve? 
If you want to show/hide the widgets that are now in layout_newInfo, then
don't use a layout. Use a widget that you put in a layout_main (vertical layout), which itself has the newInfo items and layout, then just use setVisible(true/false) on the widget as you need.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I remove layout_newInfo from layout_main in runtime given layout_newInfo is nested to layout_main?

The semantically clearer method:

```
layout_main->removeItem(layout_newInfo); // make sure layout_newInfo object deleted
                                         // after either by parent or somehow else
```

BTW, usually this should also do the same removing of nested layout:

```
delete layout_newInfo; // also removes it from upper layout
layout_main->update(); // triggers update on the screen
```

So, just 2 bottom lines of your code example should be sufficient where `layout_main->update()` call is needed only sometimes if no other update triggered.

The example from [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#takeAt) shows that deleting `QLayoutItem` which is parent for `QLayout` does remove it from upper layout structure as well (its destructor does it).

Comment: This part `layout_main = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout_main->addLayout(layout_header);
    layout_main->addLayout(layout_data);
    layout_main->addLayout(layout_buttons);
    setLayout(layout_main);` is in Constructor.

And when button is clicked appears this part
   `layout_main->addLayout(layout_newInfo);`

Comment: if `layout_newInfo` is directly nested to `layout_main` just do `delete layout_newInfo` and maybe `layout_main ->update()` as well.

Comment: but then appers some artifact. Layout doesn't disappiear it hover other layouts.

Comment: called update()? It seems to me that more code involved but in simple situation that should not be the case with 'hover'. Ok, брателло, work to do.

Answer (score 0):

Finally find an answer best way is making void method like `void showNewInfo(QString action);`

In class cpp file

```
void MainWind::showNewInfo(QString action)
{
    if(action == "true")
    {
        bt_search->setEnabled(false);
        bt_production->setEnabled(false);
        bt_drying->setEnabled(false);
        bt_storage->setEnabled(false);
        ln_spent->show();
        cb_thickness1->show();
        cb_thickness2->show();
        cb_thickness3->show();
        cb_EFL1->show();
        cb_EFL2->show();
        bt_newItem->show();
    }
    else if(action == "false")
    {
        bt_search->setEnabled(true);
        bt_production->setEnabled(true);
        bt_drying->setEnabled(true);
        bt_storage->setEnabled(true);
        ln_spent->hide();
        cb_thickness1->hide();
        cb_thickness2->hide();
        cb_thickness3->hide();
        cb_EFL1->hide();
        cb_EFL2->hide();
        bt_newItem->hide();
    }
}
```

Also there is possible to use setText(""), so next time showing fragment, it will be clear;